# Find Eclipse RAP Tutorial create View, Editor like RCP template with a View in Luna

Tags: workbench

I'm a beginner Eclipse RAP and RCP, With Eclipse RCP I can create RCP Application using template "Hello RCP" it create Editor, View, ... But RAP have no template create Editor, View.  Help me a tutorial to create simple RAP Application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Mail Template" form New Project Wizard to create simple workbench-based application.